# Modify xml while preserving whitespace

Tags: powershell

I'm running into several problems trying to replace an attribute in an XML file while preserving whitespace.

#### Attempt 1

```
$xml = [xml](get-content data.xml)
$xml.Path.To.Attribute = $value
set-content data.xml [String]$value
```

Result: Insigificant whitespace (namely newlines) are removed

#### Attempt 2

```
$xml = new-object xml
$xml.PreserveWhitespace = true
$xml.PreserveWhitespace
```

Result: `PreserveWhitespace` remains `false`

#### Attempt 3

```
$xml = get-content data.xml
$xml = [regex]::replace($xml, "pattern", "replacement")
set-content data.xml $xml
```

Result: `[regex]::replace` messes up the line endings

Am I taking crazy pills here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problems were all related: `Get-Content` returns lines of the text file, not the text itself. When cast back to a string, the lines are combined outright.

The best solution was to use:

```
$xml = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("data.xml"))
```

Comment: `[xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("data.xml"))` (just like `[xml] (Get-Content data.xml)` and - in v3+ - `[xml] (Get-Content -Raw data.xml)`) should be avoided, because it can result in misinterpretation of the XML document's character encoding; use `($xml =New-Object xml).Load((Convert-Path -LiteralPath data.xml))` or - in v5+ - `($xml = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path -LiteralPath data.xml))` instead - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71848130/45375) for details.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't working because PreserveWhiteSpace is a boolean:

```
$xml = new-object xml
$xml.PreserveWhitespace = true
$xml.PreserveWhitespace
```

Use:

```
 $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
```

Answer (score 3):

By default empty lines are ignored, in order to preserve them you can change `PreserveWhitespace` property before reading the file:

Create XmlDocument object and configure PreserveWhitespace:

```
$xmlDoc = [xml]::new()
$xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
```

Load the document:

```
$xmlDoc.Load($myFilePath)
```

or

```
$xmlDoc.LoadXml($(Get-Content $myFilePath -Raw))
```

Comment: Nice, but note that it's not a good idea to suggest `$xmlDoc.LoadXml($(Get-Content $myFilePath -Raw))`, because it delegates determining the file's character encoding to `Get-Content`, which isn't XML-aware.

Answer (score 0):

There's good information in some of the answers, but let me try to provide a **systematic summary** and to **address your own attempts**:

- In order to ***preserve insignificant whitespace* in an XML document** ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument), `[xml]` in PowerShell) **read from a file**, **`.PreserveWhitespace = $true` must be set**, notably  ***before* loading content**, such as from a file.
- However, with a file you **must *also* ensure that the file is *read* (loaded) and *saved* correctly**:

  - The **robust way to *read* XML files** is to use the **`.Load()`** method:

    - `$xml = [xml]::new(); $xml.Load((Convert-Path -LiteralPath data.xml))`

      - Note the need to use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) to ensure that the input file path is a *full* (absolute) one, which is necessary, because .NET's working directory usually *differs* from PowerShell's.
      - In PowerShell **v4-**, where the static `::new()` method for constructor calls isn't available, use the following instead:
        `$xml = New-Object xml; $xml.Load((Convert-Path -LiteralPath data.xml))`
    - To be safe, **do *not* read XML files *as plain text***: Notably, **`[xml] [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("data.xml")`** - from [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6073198/45375) - and its **v3+** PowerShell (near) equivalent<sup>[1]</sup> - **`[xml] (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath data.xml)` are *not* robust**, because they can cause the XML file's character encoding to be *misinterpreted*, as it is possible for the true encoding to *only* be detectable via the XML declaration's `encoding` attribute - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71848130/45375) for details.
  - The **robust way to *save* an XML document to a file** is to use the **`.Save()`** method

    - `$xml.Save((Convert-Path -LiteralPath data.xml))`

      - Note: More work is needed when saving to a file that *doesn't exist yet*, because `Convert-Path` unfortunately only works with existing path as of PowerShell 7.3.3 (see [GiHub issue #2993](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2993), in which a *future* `-SkipPathValidation` parameter has been green-lit); e.g.:

        ```bash
         # Note: If there's a chance that the current location isn't a *file-system*
         #       location, replace $PWD.ProviderPath below with 
         #       (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath

         # Save to file 'new.xml' in the current location.
         $xml.Save((Join-Path $PWD.ProviderPath new.xml))

         # More flexible PowerShell (Core) 7+ alternative:
         $xml.Save[IO.Path]::GetFullPath('new.xml', $PWD.ProviderPath))
        ```
    - The same argument applies as to *reading* XML files:

      - To be safe, **do *not* save XML document *as plain text*** (such as [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content))
      - As with reading, you could end up with the wrong character encoding; only using `.Save()` honors the `encoding` attribute specified in the XML declaration.

To put it all together:

```bash
# Construct an empty [xml] instance.
$xml = [xml]::new() # In PSv4-: New-Object xml

# Instruct it to preserve whitespace when content is loaded later,
# as well as on saving.
$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true

# Load the document from your file
# Note the use of Convert-Path to ensure that a *full* path is used.
$xmlFileFullPath = Convert-Path -LiteralPath data.xml
$xml.Load($xmlFileFullPath)

# ... modify $xml

# Save the modified document back to the file.
# Note: If you were to write to a *different* file, again be 
#       sure to specify a *full* path.
$xml.Save($xmlFileFullPath)
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

##### Re Attempt 1

> `$xml = [xml](get-content data.xml)`

- Because [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) by default reads a text file *line by line*, so that information about the original *newlines* is invariably *lost* in the process.
- Therefore, this method of loading an XML file is *fundamentally* unsuited to preserving the original whitespace in the file, as you've discovered yourself. However, as discussed, `[xml] [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("data.xml")` and `[xml] (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath data.xml)` aren't fully robust either - use `.Load()` instead.

Apart from that, preserving the original whitespace requires *opt-in*, which the idiom (`[xml] (<# XML text, possibly from a file #>`) doesn't support, given that the `[xml]` instance's
`.PreserveWhitespace` property must be set to `$true` *before* content is loaded.

> `set-content data.xml [String]$xml`

As discussed, `Set-Content` also isn't a robust way to save an XML document to a file. Even if no encoding problems happen to arise, the absence of `-NoNewLine` (v5+) would result in a *platform-native* newline getting appended to the file, which may be at odds with the file's original newline format.

Additionally, `[String]$xml` does *not* return the *XML text* of an `[xml]` instance - you need `.OuterXml` for that.

##### Re Attempt 2

> `$xml.PreserveWhitespace = true`

This is a simple *syntax* problem:

- PowerShell's Boolean (`[bool]`) constants are `$true` and `$false`, so `true` should be `$true`
- Neglecting to use `$` does not cause a syntax *error*, however: it causes `true` to be interpreted *as a command* (a PowerShell cmdlet, script, function, external program, ...), and if there is none by that name,<sup>[2]</sup> an unrecognized-command error is emitted that *terminates the statement*, so that *no property assignment takes place*.

##### Re Attempt 3

> Result: `[regex]::replace` messes up the line endings

No: [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-string)) has *no* effect on line endings (newlines).
(As an aside: consider using PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) instead.)

Instead, the problem - loss of newlines due to creating an *array of lines* - occurred earlier, in your `Get-Content` call, as previously discussed.

---

<sup>[1] It is only fully equivalent in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which - like .NET APIs - defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8. *Windows PowerShell*, by contrast, assumes *ANSI* encoding when reading a file without a BOM.</sup>

<sup>[2] On *Unix*-like platform, there actually *is* an external program named `true`, which produces *no output*, which - when PowerShell coerces that to a `[bool]` - becomes `$false`.</sup>