# Strange characters found in XML file and PowerShell output after exporting from Excel: â€‹

Tags: excel, xml, powershell

I have an XML file that I'm trying to read with PowerShell. However when I read it, the output of some of the XML objects have the following characters in them: â€‹

I simply downloaded an XML file I needed from a third-party, which opens in Excel. Then I grab the columns I need and paste them into a new Excel Workbook. Then I map the fields with an XML Schema and then export it as an XML file, which I then use for scripting.

In the Excel spreadsheet my data *looks* clean, but then when I export it and run the PS script, these strange characters appear in the output. The characters even appear in the actual XML file after exporting. What am I doing wrong?

I tried using `-Encoding UTF8`, but I'm relatively new to PowerShell and am not sure how to appropriately apply it to my script. Appreciate any help!

**PowerShell**

```
$xmlpath = 'Path\To\The\File.xml'

[xml]$xmldata = (Get-Content $xmlpath)

$xmldata.applications.application.name
```

**Example of Output**

```
â€‹ABC_DEF_GHIâ€‹.comâ€‹â€‹
â€‹JKL_MNO_PQRSâ€‹.comâ€‹
TUV_WXY_Z.com
AB_CD_EF_GHâ€‹.com
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2477452/1030675

Comment: "â€‹" is "Mojibake" for the U+200B "Zero Width Space". It is what happens when a Zero Width Space gets encoded in UTF-8 but the bytes (0xE2 0x80 0x8B) are interpreted as Windows-1252.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a prime example of why you shouldn't use the idiom 
<del>`[xml]$xmldata = (Get-Content $xmlpath)`</del> - as convenient as it is.<sup>[1]</sup> The problem is indeed one of character encoding: your file is UTF-8-encoded, but Windows PowerShell's `Get-Content` cmdlet interprets it as ANSI-encoded in the absence of a BOM - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2477452/1030675) explains the encoding part in detail.<sup>Thanks, [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2477452/1030675).</sup>

Instead, **to ensure that the XML file's character encoding is interpreted correctly**, use the following:

```sh
# Note: If you know that $xmlPath contains a *full*, native path,
#       you don't need the Convert-Path call.
($xmlData = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path -LiteralPath $xmlPath))
```

This delegates interpretation of the character encoding to the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load) .NET API method, which not only assumes the proper default for XML (UTF-8), but also respects any explicit encoding specification as part of the XML declaration, if present (e.g., 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`)

See also:

- the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087177/45375) for background information.
- [GitHub proposal #14505](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14505), which proposes introducing a `New-Xml` cmdlet that robustly parses XML files.

---

<sup>[1] If you *happen to know* the encoding of the input file ahead of time, you can *get away with* using `Get-Content`'s `-Encoding` parameter in your original approach (`[xml]$xmldata = (Get-Content -Encoding utf8 $xmlpath`), but the `.Load()`-based approach is much more robust.</sup>